# Why is my website not showing up as an embed (OG) in Discord?

Tags: javascript, php, html

It used to be that when I sent my website to Discord, i.e. the link, a box would appear underneath with the name, image and link, but lately that hasn't been the case, I have also edited my website several times, can anyone help me?

Index.php:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <!-- ---------- HTML -->
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta name="robots" content="index" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
  <!-- ---------- ALLGEMEIN -->
  <title>Home | snoopti.de</title>
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="Home" />
  <meta property="og:title" content="Home | snoopti.de" />
  <meta name="description" content="Herzlich Willkommen auf meiner Webseite!" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="Herzlich Willkommen auf meiner Webseite!" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="snoopti, jonas, jonas grimm, snooptihd" />
  <meta name="author" content="snoopti" />
  <meta name="copyright" content="Jonas Grimm" />
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#050014cc" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="/assets/bilder/og/main.png" />
  <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png" />
  <meta property="og:image:width" content="1000" />
  <meta property="og:image:height" content="1000" />
  <link rel="icon" href="/cloud/logo.png" type="image/png" />
  <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
  <link rel="sitemap" type="application/xml" title="Sitemap" href="/sitemap.xml" />
  <!-- SCRIPTS -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <!-- ---------- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/links/style.css" />
  <!-- -------------------- PERMA -------------------- -->
  <?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/assets/head.php'; ?>
</head>

<body>
  <?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/assets/header.php'; ?>
  <main align="center">
    <div class="block">
      <!--Timer-->
      <div class="timer">
        <p> 100 Spieler Minecraft Event</p>
        <p>Start: <span class="countdown" title="01.01.2024"></span></p>
        <p>Ende: <span class="countdown" title="07.01.2024"></span></p>
        <script src="/assets/timer.js"></script>
      </div>

      <div class="line"></div>
      <!--Main-->
      <h2>Was du hier findest!</h2>
      <p>
        Auf dieser Seite findest du verschiedene Dinge. Zum Beispiel eine Linkliste, das Kontaktformular, meine Social Links, nützliche Tools und andere coole Sachen. Ich wollte schon immer eine eigene Webseite haben und jetzt habe ich sie gemacht. Ich habe klein angefangen und mich immer weiter verbessert, so dass du jetzt diese Seite sehen kannst!
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <h2>Interessante Seiten</h2>
      <div class="links-list">
        <?php
        $homeseiten = [
          "Chat" => "http://chat.snoopti.de",
          "Alle Seiten" => "/links",
          "Uploader" => "/uploader",
        ];
        foreach ($homeseiten as $text => $url) :
        ?>
          <a class="links-item" href="<?= $url ?>"><?= $text ?></a>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </div>
      <div class="links-list">
        <?php
        $verknüpfungen = [
          "YouTube" => "/youtube",
          "X-Twitter" => "/x",
          "Instagram" => "/instagram",
          "Reddit" => "/reddit",
          "TikTok" => "/tiktok",
          "Twitch" => "/twitch",
          "GitHub" => "/github",
          "SoundCloud" => "/soundcloud",
        ];
        foreach ($verknüpfungen as $text => $url) : ?>
          <a class="links-item-social <?= strtolower($text) ?>" href="<?= $url ?>" target="_blank" title="<?= $text ?>"><i class="fa-brands fa-<?= strtolower($text) ?>"></i></a>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <h2>Bleibe in Verbindung!</h2>
      <p>AAuf dem Discord-Server kannst du dich mit anderen Benutzern austauschen und neue Kontakte knüpfen. Wenn du Fragen hast, kannst du entweder ein Support-Ticket erstellen oder die Community um Hilfe bitten.</p>
      <br>
      <a href="/discord" class="button">Trete dem Discord Server bei!</a>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <div class="links-list">
        <div class="links-item" id="installApp">Web-App herunterladen</div>
        <script>
          let deferredPrompt;
          window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
            deferredPrompt = e;
          });

          const installApp = document.getElementById('installApp');
          installApp.addEventListener('click', async () => {
            if (deferredPrompt !== null) {
              deferredPrompt.prompt();
              const {
                outcome
              } = await deferredPrompt.userChoice;
              if (outcome === 'accepted') {
                deferredPrompt = null;
              }
            }
          });
        </script>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/assets/footer.php'; ?>
</body>

</html>
```

Header.php:

```html
<header>
    <div align="center">
        <a href="/" class="logo" draggable="false">
            <img src="/cloud/title.webp" draggable="false" alt="logo">
        </a>
    </div>
    <nav align="center">
        <a href="/" style="font-style: italic;">START</a>
        <a href="/links">Links</a>
        <a href="/projekte">Projekte</a>
        <a href="/tools">Tools</a>
        <a href="/kontakt">Kontakt</a>
        <a href="/discord" class="right" target="_blank">Discord</a>
        <a href="/chat" class="right" target="_blank">Chat</a>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Footer.php:

```html
<?php
$jahr = date("Y");
$uhrzeit = date("H:i");
?>

<footer>
    <p>
        &copy; <span class="autoCopyright"><?php echo $jahr; ?></span> snoopti.de | Created with <span class="text-red"><?php echo "<3"; ?></span>
        by Jonas Grimm
    </p>
</footer>
```

i mean this:
[image: BEFORE]
[image: AFTER]

I haven't tried anything because I don't know what to do

Comment: probably nothing to do with your sites source code since its not visible like that to any other server - have you made any changes recently to anything at all

Comment: Did you mean the Discord server? but other links work: https://i.imgur.com/FkdpoDs.png

Comment: Why would I mean the discord server? No, your web page

Comment: I removed the A record of one of my subdomains and submitted my main site to Google Search Console and AdSense today. Could this be the reason?

Comment: any change with the actual site in question?

Comment: Maybe your image isn't big enough?  OG images should be 1200x1200.  See https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/71882/how-to-make-facebook-link-share-thumbnails-larger/71965#71965